# Bootstrap 4 Video Embed won't Autoplay in iframe

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 I need my embedded Youtube link to autoplay.
 I haven't seen anything in the documentation on how to get it to autoplay. Everything I've read online has autoplay in a  tag, but not in the  tag the way Bootstrap has responsive embeds listed. I tried adding 'autoplay' in the iframe tag to no avail. Please let me know what I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

Paul was close, the answer was to add ?autoplay=1 to the end of the embedded url. Thanks! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: glad you got it fixed !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding &autoplay=1 to the end of the youtube link

Comment: That didn't work. That removed the preview from page load. Thank you for trying though :) I appreciate it.